# About OOP self parameter unfilled

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have developed a simple program that encrypts data, but I don't know what wrong with this.
It's showing self parameter unfilled. Where I have made the mistake?
This is my code.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
 
 
class Encryption:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = open("secret.key", "rb").read()
 
    def encrypting_text(self, data):
        data = data.encode()
        key = self.key
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted_message = f.encrypt(data).decode()
        print(encrypted_message)
 
 
Encryption.encrypting_text(data='hello world!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `instance` of the class to call its method, not the `class` itself (since `encrypting_text` is not declared as a `classmethod`). `self` refers to the instance of the current class:

```
# Encryption() is the 'instance' of class 'Encryption'
Encryption().encrypting_text(data='hello world!')
```